# Adyen web service access with .Net

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am trying to implement Adyen recurring payment to my web application (C# .Net 4) but being relatively new to web services I am not sure I am doing it the right way.

In short the payment provider exposes a WSDL url for that purpose (https://pal-test.adyen.com/pal/Recurring.wsdl) and I added it in Visual Studio 2010 as a Service Reference (i.e. Add Service Reference > Advanced > Add Web Reference)

I then went on and created a test page, to make sure the connection was operational (see code below) and retrieve the details of a test subscription that I created previously. However I am getting an exception when executing the 'listRecurringDetails' action with the error message is 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object." and I cannot figure where I am going wrong.

Any feedback would be welcome.

#

```
public partial class Store_ServiceTest : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Recurring proxy = new Recurring();
        ICredentials usrCreds = new NetworkCredential("[username]", "[password]");
        proxy.Credentials = usrCreds;

        try
        {
            RecurringDetailsRequest thisUserDetail = new RecurringDetailsRequest();
            thisUserDetail.merchantAccount = "[some reference]";
            thisUserDetail.shopperReference = "[some reference]";
            thisUserDetail.recurring.contract = "RECURRING";

            RecurringDetailsResult recContractDetails = proxy.listRecurringDetails(thisUserDetail);
            string createDate = recContractDetails.creationDate.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string err = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            proxy.Dispose();
        }        
    }
}
```

Call Stack

> App_Web_4h0noljo.dll!Store_ServiceTest.Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 38    C#

Output window

A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
An exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_4h0noljo.dll
The thread '' (0x15d0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: What debugger says? Please post stacktrace.

Comment: Hi Tomas. Thanks for your comment. The call stack does not seem to be  showing much so I have added the content of the output window as well. Let me know your thoughts. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good. The key is to add the Recurring service as a
Service Reference instead of as a Web Reference. It should work if the
app configuration file contains:

```
<system.serviceModel>
 <bindings>
     <basicHttpBinding>
         <binding name="AdyenHttpBinding">
           <security mode="Transport">
             <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
             <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" realm="Adyen PAL Service Authentication"> <!--Adyen PAL Service Authentication-->
               <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never"/>
             </transport>
           </security>
         </binding>
     </basicHttpBinding>
 </bindings>
 <client>
   <endpoint address="https://pal-test.adyen.com/pal/servlet/soap/Payment" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="AdyenHttpBinding" contract="Adyen.Payment.PaymentPortType" name="PaymentHttpPort"/>
   <endpoint address="https://pal-test.adyen.com/pal/servlet/soap/Recurring" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="AdyenHttpBinding" contract="Adyen.Recurring.RecurringPortType" name="RecurringHttpPort"/>
 </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Kind Regards,
Sander Rasker (Adyen)

Comment: Thanks for your help Sander. Adding the references to the web config is a good move too!

Comment: Quick note regarding  thisUserDetail.recurring.contract = "RECURRING" to point out that  this was still generating the 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' error so I went for your suggestion thisUserDetail.recurring = new Adyen.Recurring(){contract = "RECURRING"}; and that did the job ;-)

Comment: When i am adding service reference, it is asking for some username and password. How can i get these credentials